# Can't find a way to get Twitch API information through requests.py

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, twitch-api

I am stuck on this API thing. I want to print the incoming json file (channel points in specific) but it just prints the whole page in html format. Here is my code:

```py
import requests
import json

client_id = secret
oauth_token = secret

my_uri = 'https://localhost'

header = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {oauth_token}"}

url = f'https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={my_uri}&response_type=id_token&scope=channel:read:redemptions+openid&state=c3ab8aa609ea11e793ae92361f002671&claims={"id_token":{"email_verified":null}}'

response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

print(response.text)
```

My hypothesis is that either the `url` or the `header` is the problem. The twitch API is made for c# or js originally but I don't know how to convert that information to python.

I would also like to know how to do the "PING" and "PONG" thing that Twitch is writing about in the API

Answer (score 0):

`response.text` show the html text

`response.json` show the json

tell me if it work now

Comment: The only response I get is `<response [200]>` which I think means that it is not an error. I therefore think that the problem is within the `url` or the `header`.

Comment: if you print(response) you will get <response [200]>
you need to print(response.json)

Comment: That is what I did, if I print `response.json` i get `<response [200]>` and the same when I print `response` alone.

Comment: ther is no json you get html text so json does nothing cos you didnt have any json in the response

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the url or the header, because it should return a json file

Answer (score 0):

`response.json()` will return you the data in JSON format